# Create a file with the filename being an item in a list

Tags: python-3.x

When I run this it creates a file with a space at the beginning of the filename but I just want it to be the name from the list(without the space), how do I do this?

If I use with open("" + item, "w") as f: i get an error message - IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

```
import os

directory_path=os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

selllist='#list-of-files-sell'
buylist='#list-of-files-buy'

sell_list_file_content = open(directory_path + "/" + selllist, "r").read()
buy_list_file_content = open(directory_path + "/" + buylist, "r").read()


sellitems = sell_list_file_content.split("#")
buyitems = buy_list_file_content.split("#")


for item in sellitems:
    with open(" " + item, "w") as f:
        f.write(" ")

for item in buyitems:
    with open(" " + item, "w") as f:
        f.write(" ")
```

Comment: Which error message do you get when you use "" + item?

Comment: Have you tried it without the initial quotes  
for item in sellitems:
    with open(item, "w") as f:
        f.write(" ")

Comment: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''

Comment: with open(item, "w") - this doesnt work same error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use strip to get rid of the spaces, although '"" + item ' should work. It would be a quick fix, but I suggest you look into why that is happening.

```
with open( (" " + item).strip(), 'w')
```

You could also use casting and not have to use quotation marks

```
with open( str(item), 'w')
```

Comment: neither of these work they produce same error message IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Comment: Hey there! That's a whole different problem. Could you try the 'w+' option? It seems like a problem while truncating the file. If that doesn't work, make sure you have the necessary privileges to write in the folder.

Comment: w+ option fixed it:

    for item in sellitems:
        with open(" " + item, "w+") as f:
            f.write(" ")